# How to exit fullscreen?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, windows

My Minecraft just zoomed in all of a sudden and I don't know how to get it back. It takes up the full screen, not even leaving room for the task bar at the bottom:

[image: What it looks like for me]

This is really annoying. I even tried restarting my computer but it didn't work.

Answer (score 14):

## F11 for Fullscreen

By default, <kbd>F11</kbd> (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> on some keyboards) toggles fullscreen mode.

If that doesn't help, pause the game (by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>) and go into **Options…** → **Controls…** and check your keybinding for toggling fullscreen mode (under the "Miscellaneous" section).

Alternatively, you can go into **Options…** → **Video Settings…** and click "Fullscreen: ON" to turn it off manually.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, you can just hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and move the mouse to the top right and hit the small/big window button (not literally, though, as you will break your computer).

There is also another way to get stuck in the fullscreen, and that would be if you hit <kbd>F11</kbd>. In that case just close Minecraft and restart it. It should then be back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *%appdata%*, click on the *.mineraft* folder, and in the search bar search for *options.txt*.
Upon clicking *options.txt*, you can find 'Fullscreen:true'. Toggle the state from 'true' to 'false', and relaunch Minecraft. You will no longer be in fullscreen mode.

Comment: Or you can just change it in the settings menu

Answer (score 0):

If your not okay with Mincraft covering your screen fully, you can press F11 this works in most of the times, but if it does not work you can try

1. Close MINECRAFT  (including mincraft launcher) start it again.

2)Open minecraft manually press "Esc" go to options--controls--see the key for your toggle fullscreen and use it

3. go to minecraft press "Esc" go to options, go to video settings, there you see the option to exit fullscreen..you can press that option
   THANK YOU

Answer (score -3):

I found out that if you go to file then go back to the download, scroll to the time you downloaded the Minecraft launchers then click it and select repair and that will make Minecraft to reset all changes in settings and keep your data!

Comment: ...What? What are you talking about and could you explain further?